# How to prevent double writes to database from a class that gets initialised on startup of tomcat?

Tags: java, servletcontextlistener

I seem to have gotten stuck nastily here.

I'm loading a singleton class on startup of tomcat (using load-on-startup in web.xml) and the values get loaded from a database. After loading, a set of data is written to the same database but in different tables. The thing is, data is loading perfectly but the writes are happening twice. I understand that writes are happening twice because I have 2 instances of the webapp.

However, 2 instances of the same webapp are required. I cannot change the folder structure either. Can't make changes in server.xml as it is auto generated. (please dont suggest these, cant do!)

I tried using servletcontextlistener to initialize the singleton class but the database framework Im using doesn't get loaded at the time and I'm getting null pointer exceptions in query results. So, the singleton class is not getting loaded with values from the database.

I'm using eclipse.

How do I go about this (if that is even possible)?

I'm looking to see if servletcontextlistener would do the job by loading the db framework beforehand. Any solutions?

Comment: Please add some code so we can help. There's no way to debug code you can't see.

Answer (score 1):

A solution for this would be to create your own "DB lock" i.e, when any instance of webapp comes up, let it check for a table - let us call it "lock" and if it doesn't exist in the DB, then let it create it and do the inserts. If the next instance of your webapp starts, then if it sees that the lock has already been taken, then it can either wait for the lock to be released or just skip the init.

If your other webapps have to do their own upgrades after your first webapp has done it's job, then create a table that maintains state of the DB upgrade. Each webapp updates this table once it does it's job during initialization.